# Black screen using Oculus PC SDK with OpenGL and Qt

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, oculus

I'm trying to make a basic test with the Oculus
I use the PC SDK 1.6, OpenGL and Qt.

I first began with https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/pcsdk/latest/concepts/dg-render/

Then i lookd at different topic but i cant figure out what i do wrong but especially where are my mistakes..

It seams the initialize part is correct. The Oculus shows the health warning message, but all I see is a black screen once the health warning message goes away.

Here si the code i use :

OculusManager.h

```
#ifndef OCULUSMANAGER_H
#define OCULUSMANAGER_H

#include "main.h"
#include <OVR_CAPI_GL.h>
#include <QtGui/qopengl.h>
#include <QOpenGLFunctions_4_3_Compatibility>

class OculusManager : protected QOpenGLFunctions_4_3_Compatibility
{
public:
    OculusManager();
    bool initLibOVR();
    void displayLastError();
    void run();
    void shutdown();
    void destroy();

private:

    bool mainLoop(bool value);

    ovrSession session;
    ovrGraphicsLuid luid;
    bool isOVRLibLoaded = false;
    ovrHmdDesc hmdDesc;
    ovrSizei bufferSize;
    ovrTextureSwapChain textureSwapChain;
    ovrLayerEyeFov layer;
    // Initialize VR structures, filling out description.
    ovrEyeRenderDesc eyeRenderDesc[2];
    ovrVector3f      hmdToEyeViewOffset[2];
    ovrVector3f hmdToEyeOffset[2];
    double sensorSampleTime;
    bool isVisible = true;
    // it needs to be updated each new frame
    long long frameIndex = 0;
    // Initialize a default Pose
    ovrPosef eyeRenderPose[2];

    bool end = false;

    void openglError();
};

#endif // OCULUSMANAGER_H
```

OculusManager.cpp

```
#include "oculusmanager.h"


OculusManager::OculusManager()
{
}


bool OculusManager::initLibOVR(){

    if(initializeOpenGLFunctions() == false){
        qDebug() << "Impossible to load OpenGL functions";
        return false;
    }

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    // Accept fragment if it closer to the camera than the former one
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);

    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);                        // Enable Smooth Shading
    glClearDepth(1.0f);                         // Depth Buffer Setup
    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);          // Really Nice Perspective Calculations


    //background color
    glClearColor(0., 0., 0., 1.0);


    if(OVR_FAILURE(ovr_Initialize(nullptr)))
    {
        return false;
    }


    if (OVR_FAILURE(ovr_Create(&session, &luid)))
    {
        return false;
    }

    //main code

    hmdDesc = ovr_GetHmdDesc(session);

    ovrSizei recommenedTex0Size = ovr_GetFovTextureSize(session, ovrEye_Left, hmdDesc.DefaultEyeFov[0], 1.0f);
    ovrSizei recommenedTex1Size = ovr_GetFovTextureSize(session, ovrEye_Right,hmdDesc.DefaultEyeFov[1], 1.0f);

    bufferSize;
    bufferSize.w  = recommenedTex0Size.w + recommenedTex1Size.w;
    bufferSize.h = std::max( recommenedTex0Size.h, recommenedTex1Size.h );


    ovrTextureSwapChainDesc ovrTextdesc = {};
    ovrTextdesc.Type = ovrTexture_2D;
    ovrTextdesc.ArraySize = 1;
    ovrTextdesc.Format = OVR_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM_SRGB;
    ovrTextdesc.Width = bufferSize.w;
    ovrTextdesc.Height = bufferSize.h;
    ovrTextdesc.MipLevels = 1;
    ovrTextdesc.SampleCount = 1;
    ovrTextdesc.StaticImage = ovrFalse;



    if(OVR_SUCCESS(ovr_CreateTextureSwapChainGL(session, &ovrTextdesc, &textureSwapChain)))
    {
        int length = 0;
        if (OVR_FAILURE(ovr_GetTextureSwapChainLength(session, textureSwapChain, &length))){
            return false;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
        {
            GLuint chainTexId;
            if (OVR_FAILURE(ovr_GetTextureSwapChainBufferGL(session, textureSwapChain, i, &chainTexId))){
                return false;
            }

            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, chainTexId);

            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

        }


        // Generate frame buffer to render
        GLuint fboID;
        glGenFramebuffers(1, &fboID);
        // Generate depth buffer of the frame buffer
        GLuint depthBuffID;
        glGenTextures(1, &depthBuffID);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthBuffID);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        GLenum internalFormat = GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24;
        GLenum type = GL_UNSIGNED_INT;
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, internalFormat, bufferSize.w, bufferSize.h, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, type, NULL);


        // FloorLevel will give tracking poses where the floor height is 0
        ovr_SetTrackingOriginType(session, ovrTrackingOrigin_FloorLevel);

        eyeRenderDesc[0] = ovr_GetRenderDesc(session, ovrEye_Left, hmdDesc.DefaultEyeFov[0]);
        eyeRenderDesc[1] = ovr_GetRenderDesc(session, ovrEye_Right, hmdDesc.DefaultEyeFov[1]);
        hmdToEyeViewOffset[0] = eyeRenderDesc[0].HmdToEyeOffset;
        hmdToEyeViewOffset[1] = eyeRenderDesc[1].HmdToEyeOffset;

        // Initialize our single full screen Fov layer.

        layer.Header.Type      = ovrLayerType_EyeFov;
        layer.Header.Flags     = 0;
        layer.ColorTexture[0]  = textureSwapChain;
        layer.ColorTexture[1]  = textureSwapChain;
        layer.Fov[0]           = eyeRenderDesc[0].Fov;
        layer.Fov[1]           = eyeRenderDesc[1].Fov;

        ovrSizei rectsize;
        rectsize.w  =  bufferSize.w / 2;
        rectsize.h =  bufferSize.h;

        ovrVector2i rectPosL;
        rectPosL.x = 0;
        rectPosL.y = 0;

        ovrVector2i rectPosR;
        rectPosR.x = bufferSize.w / 2;
        rectPosR.y = 0;

        ovrRecti rectLeft, rectRight;
        rectLeft.Pos = rectPosL;
        rectLeft.Size = rectsize;

        rectRight.Pos = rectPosR;
        rectRight.Size = rectsize;


        layer.Viewport[0] = rectLeft;
        layer.Viewport[1] = rectRight;
        // ld.RenderPose and ld.SensorSampleTime are updated later per frame.

        isOVRLibLoaded = true;

    }


    return isOVRLibLoaded;

}


void OculusManager::run(){

    mainLoop(true);
}

bool OculusManager::mainLoop(bool value){


    // Get both eye poses simultaneously, with IPD offset already included.
    double displayMidpointSeconds = ovr_GetPredictedDisplayTime(session, 0);

    ovrTrackingState hmdState = ovr_GetTrackingState(session, displayMidpointSeconds, ovrTrue);
    ovr_CalcEyePoses(hmdState.HeadPose.ThePose, hmdToEyeViewOffset, layer.RenderPose);


    openglError();

   // qDebug() << hmdState.HeadPose.ThePose.Position.x << hmdState.HeadPose.ThePose.Position.y << hmdState.HeadPose.ThePose.Position.z;

    // Get texture swap index where we must draw our frame
    GLuint curTexId;
    // Get next available index of the texture swap chain
    int currentIndex = 0;
    ovr_GetTextureSwapChainCurrentIndex(session, textureSwapChain, &currentIndex);
    ovr_GetTextureSwapChainBufferGL(session, textureSwapChain, currentIndex, &curTexId);


    // Call ovr_GetRenderDesc each frame to get the ovrEyeRenderDesc, as the returned values (e.g. HmdToEyeOffset) may change at runtime.
    eyeRenderDesc[0] = ovr_GetRenderDesc(session, ovrEye_Left, hmdDesc.DefaultEyeFov[0]);
    eyeRenderDesc[1] = ovr_GetRenderDesc(session, ovrEye_Right, hmdDesc.DefaultEyeFov[1]);
    hmdToEyeOffset[0] = eyeRenderDesc[0].HmdToEyeOffset;
    hmdToEyeOffset[1] = eyeRenderDesc[1].HmdToEyeOffset;
    // Get eye poses, feeding in correct IPD offset
    ovr_GetEyePoses(session, frameIndex, ovrTrue, hmdToEyeOffset, eyeRenderPose, &sensorSampleTime);

    if (isVisible)
    {

        glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0);
        glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0);
        // Clear the frame buffer

        // Render Scene to Eye Buffers
        for (int eye = 0; eye < 2; eye++)
        {

            // Set the left or right vertical half of the buffer as the viewport
            glViewport(eye == ovrEye_Left ? 0 : bufferSize.w / 2, 0, bufferSize.w / 2, bufferSize.h);
            glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

        }

        // Do not forget to increment the frameIndex!
        frameIndex++;

        // Commit the changes to the texture swap chain
        ovr_CommitTextureSwapChain(session, textureSwapChain);
    }


    layer.Header.Type = ovrLayerType_EyeFov;
    // Tell to the Oculus compositor that our texture origin is at the bottom left
    layer.Header.Flags = ovrLayerFlag_TextureOriginAtBottomLeft;   // Because OpenGL | Disable head tracking
    // Set the Oculus layer eye field of view for each view
    for (int eye = 0; eye < 2; ++eye)
    {
        // Set the color texture as the current swap texture
        layer.ColorTexture[eye] = textureSwapChain;
        // Set the viewport as the right or left vertical half part of the color texture
        ovrRecti rect;
        rect.Pos.x = eye == ovrEye_Left ? 0 : bufferSize.w / 2;
        rect.Pos.y = 0;
        rect.Size.h = bufferSize.h;
        rect.Size.w = bufferSize.w / 2;
        layer.Viewport[eye] =rect;
        // Set the field of view
        layer.Fov[eye] = hmdDesc.DefaultEyeFov[eye];
        // Set the pose matrix
        layer.RenderPose[eye] = eyeRenderPose[eye];
    }

    layer.SensorSampleTime = sensorSampleTime;

    // Submit frame with one layer we have.
    ovrLayerHeader* layers = &layer.Header;
    ovrResult       result = ovr_SubmitFrame(session, 0, nullptr, &layers, 1);
    if(OVR_FAILURE(result)){
        qDebug() << "ovr_submitFrame failed";
    }
    isVisible = (result == ovrSuccess);

    //TODO if response is lost, destroy everything here
    //TODO if response is lost, destroy everything here
    //TODO if response is lost, destroy everything here
    //TODO if response is lost, destroy everything here

    // This is not really needed for this application but it may be usefull for an more advanced application
    ovrSessionStatus sessionStatus;
    ovr_GetSessionStatus(session, &sessionStatus);
    if (sessionStatus.ShouldRecenter)
    {
        qDebug() << "Recenter Tracking asked by Session" ;
        ovr_RecenterTrackingOrigin(session);
    }

    return true;

}

void OculusManager::openglError(){
    GLenum error = glGetError();
    while(error !=0){
        qDebug() << "error gl : " << error;
        error = glGetError();
    }
}

void OculusManager::displayLastError(){
    ovrErrorInfo errorInfo;
    ovr_GetLastErrorInfo(&errorInfo);
    qDebug() << "Oculus Manager error : " << errorInfo.ErrorString;
}

void OculusManager::shutdown(){
    ovr_Shutdown();
}

void OculusManager::destroy(){
    ovr_Destroy(session);
}
```

Thx in advance for your help

Possible duplicate but did not helped me :

[Black Screen when rendering with Oculus SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25291131/black-screen-when-rendering-with-oculus-sdk)

[Oculus 0.8 SDK Black Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35400308/oculus-0-8-sdk-black-screen)

Answer (score 0):

> `glClearColor(0., 0., 0., 1.0);`

You should try setting the clear color to something other than black, so you know whether the framebuffer being submitted at all.  If you clear to say 'red' and the HMD is still black, then you know the framebuffer isn't getting there.  If the display is red, but everything you render is missing, then you know that your rendering code is wrong.

Speaking of which, you never actually clear the framebuffer... your example code does not contain `glClear` anywhere at all.  You just have a comment

> // clear the framebuffer

but you don't actually do it.  So it's entirely possible that your `glDrawElements` isn't doing anything because the depth test is failing for every fragment.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no solved this yet, you must set the textures received from GetTextureSwapChainBufferGL as a framebuffer using glFramebufferTexture2D.
So you have to call set framebufferTexture2D twice each time, one for each texture id (one for left and one for right). 
Currently you are drawing nothing to the textures you got from the function and so they remain black and that is what you are getting.

Hope this helps.